# Jest unit test: setTimeout not firing in async test

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I'm trying to understand how asynchronous testing works in Jest.

What I'm trying to do is similar to an example from the Jest documentation. This works fine ..

```
function doAsync(c) {
  c(true)
}

test('doAsync calls both callbacks', () => {

  expect.assertions(2);

  function callback1(data) {
    expect(data).toBeTruthy();
  }

  function callback2(data) {
    expect(data).toBeTruthy();
  }

  doAsync(callback1);
  doAsync(callback2);
});
```

But I want to delay the callback invocations so I tried this ....

```
 function doAsync(c) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('timeout fired')
      c(true)
    }, 1000)
  }
```

but the test fails with the message `Expected two assertions to be called but received zero assertion calls.`.

The log message 'timeout fired' doesn't appear in the console.

Please can someone explain why it fails?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You need to use jest's timer mocks https://jestjs.io/docs/en/timer-mocks

First you tell jest to use mock timers, then you run the timers within your test.

It would look something like:

```js
function doAsync(c) {
  setTimeout(() => {
      c(true)
    }, 1000)
}

jest.useFakeTimers()

test('doAsync calls both callbacks', () => {

  expect.assertions(2);

  function callback1(data) {
    expect(data).toBeTruthy();
  }

  function callback2(data) {
    expect(data).toBeTruthy();
  }

  doAsync(callback1);
  doAsync(callback2);

  jest.runAllTimers(); // or jest.advanceTimersByTime(1000)
});
```

Comment: It seems that now `jest.useFakeTimers()` needs to be used by every test instead of being declared in the upper scope.

Comment: @GiulioG. Thank you for this insight, it solved the issue I was having. My test was mysteriously failing after upgrading Jest from 24 to 26 (along with create-react-app from 3 to 4), so if anyone else sees this: move your call to `useFakeTimers` inside your test!

Comment: It’s a pleasure @Cécile Fecherolle

Answer (score 5):

Use of `jest.runAllTimers();` can lead to below error:

> Ran 100000 timers, and there are still more! Assuming we've hit an
> infinite recursion and bailing out...

After going through the [JEST timer mocks documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/timer-mocks#run-pending-timers), it occurred to me that the `setTimeout` goes into infinite recursion as mentioned in the docs. It is recommended to use `jest.runOnlyPendingTimers()` and this solves the infinite recursion error.

> Fast forward and exhaust only currently pending timers
> (but not any new timers that get created during that process)

> jest.runOnlyPendingTimers();

Answer (score -1):

Use the below code for the setTime out in your test case.

```
it('saveSubscription', () => {
  function doAsync(c) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      component.addSubscription();
      expect(component.subscription.freq).toEqual('immediate');
      component.saveSubscription();
      expect(component.subscription.name).toBe('Untitled 1');
    }, 30000);
  }
});
```