# How to assert on callback when using jest.useFakeTimers

Tags: jestjs, settimeout, cleartimeout, usefaketimers

I'm trying to understand how to correctly unit test a custom *debounce* method we have:

```js
// function we want to test
function debounce(func, wait = 100) {
  let timeout;

  return (...args) => {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      func.apply(this, args);
    }, wait);
  };
}
```

Here is the Jest unit test that is failing:

```js
describe('DebounceExample', () => {
  beforeAll(jest.useFakeTimers);
  afterAll(jest.useRealTimers);

  it('should debounce', () => {
    // given
    const data = 'Chuck Norris is faster than you think';
    const debounceTime = 5000;
    const callback = jest.fn();
    const debouncedFunction = debounce(callback, debounceTime);

    // when
    debouncedFunction(data);

    // then
    expect(callback).not.toHaveBeenCalled();

    // when
    jest.runAllTimers(); // jest.advanceTimersByTime(debounceTime);

    // then
    expect(callback).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Failure:

```
Error: expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled()

Expected number of calls: >= 1
Received number of calls:    0  Jest
```

I've also tried the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52638566/704681 without success

Workaround: the only way I'm able to test it so far:

```js
  it('should denounce - workaround', (done) => {
    // given
    const data = 'Chuck Norris is faster than you think';
    const debounceTime = 5000;
    const callback = jest.fn((param) => {
      // then
      expect(param).toEqual(data);
      done();
    });
    const debouncedFunction = debounce(callback, debounceTime);

    // when
    debouncedFunction(data);

    // then
    expect(callback).not.toHaveBeenCalled();

    // when (see 'then' inside callback implementation)
    jest.runAllTimers(); // jest.advanceTimersByTime(debounceTime);
  });
```

Comment: Do you have a reproducible repo since your code looks like to be working?

Comment: Tried to setup codesandbox but no luck: getting `jest.advanceTimersByTime is not a function`: https://codesandbox.io/s/jest-example-j72xu

Comment: Not sure what did you setup but you can't run your any command there.

Comment: Look on the right blank panel, there are 2 TABS, one is of the Tests. But not all `Jest` features are supported, like `runAllTimers`. You can however download the example and use `npm run test`

Comment: I did try your code but worked well as expected though

Comment: I know that the `should denounce - workaround` is working, now the question is why I'm getting `Received number of calls:    0` on the `should debounce` test...

Comment: I meant your original one works well not the workaround one :)

Comment: Hum... interesting. I'm then curious about what could make it fail on my side then, `Node` version? Using `v12.18.3`

Comment: My version is `v14.13.1`